# How to reference a recursive variable within a macro in racket

Tags: recursion, macros, racket

In Drracket I am being tasked with creating a recursive macro that can take in (edges n1 -> n2 <-> n3) for example, with n1, n2, and n3 being (define-struct node (name edges)). The -> indicates putting the second node into the edges of the first node and the <-> indicates doing it both ways. So n1 would have edges n2 and n2 would have edges n3 and n3 would have edges n2. My problem lies in Drracket recursive macros. When you have a variable with an ellipse after it, ex: (edges n1 -> n2 ...) in the pattern matcher, I don't know how to reference just n2 without also evaluating the ellipse.

```
(define-syntax edges
  (syntax-rules (-> <->)
[(edges n1 -> n2 ...)
 (begin
     (set-node-edges! n1 (cons (n2 ...) (node-edges n1))) 
   (edges n2 ...))]
[(edges n1 <-> n2 ...)
 (begin
       (begin
         (set-node-edges! n1 (cons (n2 ...) (node-edges n1)))
         (set-node-edges! n2 ... (cons 'n1 (node-edges n2 ...))))
   (edges n2 ...))]
[(edges n1)
 void]))
```

Comment: Hey, I just noticed your SO name as well. I also suffer from chronic depression and just wanted you to know that we are here for you. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the patterns you've used, the parens are actually tightly bound with the `n2`. That is `n2` *is* a list of everything else. What you actually want is a pattern that is something more like:

```
 n1 -> n2 rest ...
```

That way, the `...` is bound to the `rest`, rather than the `n2`.

I also recommend using `syntax-parse` instead of `syntax-rules`. It allows for much more clear pattern matching (as well as arbitrary computations. For example, right now you are assuming that `n1` and `n2` are identifiers, but you aren't checking it. Your macro also requres `->` and `<->` to be bound outside of that macro. With `syntax-parse`, the whole thing becomes much cleaner:

```
#lang racket
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse)) ;; <-- Needed to use syntax-parse
(define-syntax (edges stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
   #:datum-literals (-> <->)
   [(_)
    #'(begin)]
   [(_ n1:id -> n2:id rest ...)
    #'(begin .... your code here ....)]
   [(_ n1:id <-> n2:id rest ...)
    #'(begin .... your code here ....)]))
```

Inside of the `.... your code here ....` blocks, you can use `n1` to refer to `n1:id`, you can use `n2` to refer to `n2:id`, and finally, you can use something like `(n2 rest ...)` to refer to a list starting with `n2:id` and finishing with `rest ...`.

Also, note that by putting `:id` at the end of the patterns, you get automatic checking that `n1` and `n2` are identifiers.